# Python csv cell by cell iteration to find out a greater value and perform a delete on the row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, where-clause

The operation I am trying to perform is similar to this mysql delete statement :

```
    DELETE FROM ABCD WHERE val_2001>val_2000*1.5 OR val_2001>val_1999*POW(1.5,2);
```

where val_2001,val_2000, val_1999 are all column names. So the query is performing these 3 actions :

```
1. Comparing col-b with col-a 
2. OR operation with comparing col-b with col-1999(constant)
3. Deleting the whole row from the table if the condition satisfies.
```

To write this in python ( instead of mysql, since its a csv and avoiding uploading to db).
The code I have as of now, is as follows :

```
   df = pd.read_csv("singleDataFile.csv")
       for values in xrange(2000,2016):
            val2 = values+1
            df['val_'+str(val2)] = df['val_'+str(val2)].where((df['val_'+str(val2)]>df['val_'+str(values)]*1.5) |  (df['val_'+str(val2)]<df['val_'+str(values)]*0.75))

       print(df)
```

Alternative approach tried :

```
    df = pd.read_csv("singleDataFile.csv")
    cols = [ 'val_{}'.format(c) for c in range(2000, 2018)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = cols)
    df[(df.shift(axis = 1) > df * 1.5) | (df.shift(axis = 1) < df * 0.75)] = 'NULL'
```

In both cases it ends with :

```
getting an error with TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

However in both the ways it is not even attempting deletion of the entire row. how to achieve this?

CSV TABLE SNIPPET :

```
val_2000   val_2001        val_2002            val_2003
100     112.058663384525    119.070787312921    117.033250060214
100     118.300395256917    124.655238202362    128.723125524235
100     109.333236619151    116.785836024946    117.390803371386
100     120.954175930764    126.099776250454    124.491022271481
100     107.776153227575    105.560100052722    108.07490649383
100     151.596517146962    306.608812920781    124.610273175528
```

Note: there are columns before val_2000 like index rows and some name row which should not be considered for iteration as well.

Comment: I guess it is due to your multiplications by float (1.5 and 0.75) I don't understand what you are trying to do by these operations. If you want to multiply the value of the cell, add a .values

Comment: probably it would be helpful i can give csv file snippet. I am editing the question. So I am trying to remove certain rows if they do not meet a criteria..? (removing outliers)

Comment: Yeah but i still don't understand why you want to do by multpying your row ?

Comment: Its simple actually, If value of a year say 2001 is greater than 1.5 times val of 2000, then i am considering it as wrong value(outlier), hence want to delete the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem you need [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True`, then invert by `~` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#convert all values to float
df = df.astype(float)

#if some bad values (like strings in numeric) replace them to NaN
#df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

print ((df.shift(axis = 1) > df * 1.5) | (df.shift(axis = 1) < df * 0.75))
  val_2000 val_2001 val_2002 val_2003
0    False    False    False    False
1    False    False    False    False
2    False    False    False    False
3    False    False    False    False
4    False    False    False    False
5    False    False     True     True

print (~((df.shift(axis = 1) > df * 1.5) | (df.shift(axis = 1) < df * 0.75)).any(1))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool

df = df[~((df.shift(axis = 1) > df * 1.5) | (df.shift(axis = 1) < df * 0.75)).any(1)]
print (df)
   val_2000    val_2001    val_2002    val_2003
0       100  112.058663  119.070787  117.033250
1       100  118.300395  124.655238  128.723126
2       100  109.333237  116.785836  117.390803
3       100  120.954176  126.099776  124.491022
4       100  107.776153  105.560100  108.074906
```

IIUC you need:

```
const = ['val_'+ str(x) for x in range(1995,2000)]
print (const)
['val_1995', 'val_1996', 'val_1997', 'val_1998', 'val_1999']

for x in const:
    df[x] = 1
```

Comment: I try test it, i think problem is some int values - convert all columns to `floats` by `df = df.astype(float)` or some bad values, then `astype` return error. Then use `pd.to_numeric`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140068/discussion-between-viv-and-jezrael).